# Why copied layers are not being detected in the timeline on a Photoshop animation?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, animated-gif

I am trying to make an animated gif in Photoshop.
It's a simple animation, I only want an image to appear and disappear. To show a small circle blinking.
But whenever I copy the layer in the timeline and move it. When I press "play", only the original layer works as expected, and Photoshop ignores the second one. (see attached video)

I thought it was some bug of the preview, but when exported, it actually ignores the second one. Why?

[image]

P.D. I know I can just leave two layers (one on, one off), and to make them loop infinitely. But I would like to know how to fix this for other occasions.